# if batch program returns a certain message, then perform an action

Tags: batch-file

Trying to perform an automatic action with a batch script in windows.

I am launching an ADB android server, then querying the connected devices.

EDIT: my code.

```
adb start-server

adb forward tcp:2222 tcp:2222

adb devices
```

If my phone is connected the dos terminal returns:

```
List of devices attached
8663ed8d        device
```

Is there a way to perfom another action only if 8663ed8d is returned?

Comment: you mean only `8663ed8d        device` pr both strings?

Comment: Can you show us relevant parts of your code so far?  It's uncelar what "querying the connected devices" means, or how the "dos terminal returns" something.

Comment: added code, I need to perform an action only if 8663ed8d is returned. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simpler way - if you just want to find if that device is connected:

```
adb -switches |find "8663ed8d" >nul && echo yep! do action here
```

Comment: Your code triggers the adb command help list. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: The `adb -switches` is merely meant to show that you put the command you normally use there.  I am just demonstrating a batch file technique, but I don't use adb so that part is for you to fill in.  Sorry I wasn't very clear on that.

Comment: `adb devices |find "8663ed8d" >nul && ACTION` did the job, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to your question with the current information from you:

```
for /f "Tokens=1,2" %%a in ('"ADB android server"') do set "f1=%%a"&set "f2=%%b"
if "%f1%"=="8663ed8d" if "%f2%"=="device" ACTION
```

Comment: Your code triggers the adb command help list. Are you sure it is correct?